# How to get the numbers of a column in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the database as below picture shown:

[image]

I want to get the numbers under "ID" colm with "0" value in "is_parent".

How to do that with a sql query?

I want the numbers going to be link this:

1792,2304,1793,1794,2308.. etc..

Tried my best, with failed attempt, hopefully someone can help me with the correct query.

Thank you,
regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from database and echo on php page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489439/how-to-get-data-from-database-and-echo-on-php-page)

Comment: Can you please update your question and show us your best attempt at solving this problem yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it is simple

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name` WHERE is_parent= 0
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly good answer, despite the poor question.

Answer (score 0):

well, if

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name` WHERE is_parent= 0
```

fails, you may try:

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name` WHERE is_parent IN (1792,2304,1793,1794,2308....)
```

or:

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name` WHERE is_parent != 0
```

Comment: Your second two examples clearly do not work for the problem asked in the question.